# Retornar somente alguns campos do JSON na resposta da requisição (Nodejs + Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Pessoal estou com o seguinte problema, estou tentando retornar somente alguns campos como "nome" e "email" do meu objeto JSON, pois ele sozinho possui 23 atributos

```
exports.listarProfissionais = function(request, response) {
    if (request.get("Authorization") == "test") {
        ProfissionalSchema.find({}, function(erro, profissionais) {
            if (erro)
                response.json({"erro": "Erro ao listar os profissionais !"});
            else {
                response.json(profissionais); // ASSIM ELE RETORNA TODOS OS ATRIBUTOS
            }
        });
    } else {
        response.json({"erro": "profissional/listar -> Invalid access tokens"});
    }
}
```

Gostaria de retornar somente o atributo "nome" e "email" por exemplo, mas estou com extrema dificuldade em entender o conceito.

Comment: Mostra o seu método que gera o objeto json "profissionais"

Answer (score 0):

Aqui quero pegar apenas os nomes:

```js
var prof = [
 {"nome":"Jao","cep":"123"},
 {"nome":"Maria","cep":"122"},
 {"nome":"Pedro","cep":"124"},
];

var newProf = [];
prof.forEach(function(obj, k){
 Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key, kk){
   if (key == "nome") {
     newProf.push({[key]: prof[k][key]});
    }
  });
});

document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(newProf);
```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que esse seu objeto profissionais é um Array de Collections, você poderá usar a função map, nativa do JS, para essa finalidade:

```
ProfissionalSchema.find({}, function(erro, profissionais) {
        if (erro)
            response.json({"erro": "Erro ao listar os profissionais !"});
        else {
            //mapear apenas os atributos necessários em um novo array
            profissionais_normalizado= profissionais.map( (prof) => {
               return {"nome" : prof.nome, "email" : prof.email}
            })
            //responder a requisição com esse novo array
            response.json(profissionais_normalizado); 
        }
    });
```

A função map itera sobre cada item do array que está chamando o método, e recebe uma função de mapeamento, o que essa função retorna, irá compor o array de resultado.
Veja mais sobre ela aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Entendi, mas a função .map() não está sendo reconhecida, esqueci de mencionar que a variável "profissionais" é um "array de JSONs".

Comment: O método map() faz parte do objeto Array (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Dá um console.log(JSON.stringify(profissionais)) e cola o conteúdo aqui p/ gente ver como estão organizados os dados...